# Transpose data inside MySQL - from column values to row values

Tags: mysql, pivot

Let's say in my case I have a table like:

```
id  group_id    text        data    empty1  empty2  empty3  empty4  empty5

1   20      AB      data1
2   20      AB      data2
3   21      AC      data3
4   20      AB      data4
5   21      AC      data5
6   22      AD      data6
7   22      AD      data7
8   22      AD      data8
9   23      AF      data9
```

As you can see - field 'text' contains some same data - according to field 'group_id'.
The only difference that 'text' is alphanumeric and 'group_id' is numeric.
Field 'data' contains various text information (varchar (255))

Is it possible and HOW to process the table inside MySQL to copy (or move) the values from 'data' field to 'empty' fields in accordance with group_id, as follows :

```
id  group_id    text        data        empty1      empty2      empty3  empty4  empty5

1   20      AB      data1       data1       data2       data4
2   20      AB      data2
3   21      AC      data3       data3       data5
4   20      AB      data4
5   21      AC      data5
6   22      AD      data6       data6       data7       data8
7   22      AD      data7
8   22      AD      data8
9   23      AF      data9       data9
```

May be it's easier to fill ALL first - I mean

```
id  group_id    text        data        empty1      empty2      empty3  empty4  empty5

1   20      AB      data1       data1       data2       data4
2   20      AB      data2       data1       data2       data4
```

and as a final step - just delete duplicates basing on group_id - so that in the end we have a clear FINAL table like

```
id  group_id    text        data        empty1      empty2      empty3  empty4  empty5

1   20      AB      data1       data1       data2       data4
3   21      AC      data3       data3       data5
6   22      AD      data6       data6       data7       data8
9   23      AF      data9       data9
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the data into the format that you want by using variable and aggregate function to transpose the rows of data into columns.

The basic syntax to get the data in the format that you want will be:

```
select d.id,
  d.group_id,
  d.text,
  t.data,
  d.empty1,
  d.empty2,
  d.empty3,
  d.empty4,
  d.empty5
from yourtable t
inner join 
(
  select min(id) id,
    group_id,
    text,
    max(case when row=1 then data end) empty1,
    max(case when row=2 then data end) empty2,
    max(case when row=3 then data end) empty3,
    max(case when row=4 then data end) empty4,
    max(case when row=5 then data end) empty5
  from
  (
    select id, 
      group_id,
      text,
      data,
      @row:=case 
              when @pg=group_id and @pt=text
              then @row
              else 0 end +1 row,
      @pg:=group_id,
      @pt:=text
    from yourtable 
    cross join
    (
      select @row:=0, @pg:=0, @pt:=null
    ) c
    order by group_id, text, id
  ) src
  group by group_id, text
  order by group_id, text, id
) d
  on t.id = d.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2acc3/19). This query will give you a result:

```
| ID | GROUP_ID | TEXT |  DATA | EMPTY1 | EMPTY2 | EMPTY3 | EMPTY4 | EMPTY5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       20 |   AB | data1 |  data1 |  data2 |  data4 | (null) | (null) |
|  3 |       21 |   AC | data3 |  data3 |  data5 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  6 |       22 |   AD | data6 |  data6 |  data7 |  data8 | (null) | (null) |
|  9 |       23 |   AF | data9 |  data9 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: This code created by @bluefeet works perfectly ! 
Now looking for a way to adjust the one for the table where there are additional fields BETWEEN **id** and **group_id** as follows:   

**id** ; number ; name ; **group_id** ; **text** ; **data** ; title ; description ;  **empty1 ; empty2 ; empty3 ; empty4 ; empty5** ; level ; rank ; date ; time ;    so the NON-BOLD fields should be left INTACT.

Comment: @Serge if you have a different problem that requires a different solution, please don't change the requirements here - create a new question. Nobody can read what you're trying to demonstrate in that comment anyway.

Comment: @Serge is it possible you could take the information Bluefeet has given you and perhaps use that to come up with future answers for your problems using a process I often refer to as learning.

Comment: @Serge You should be able to modify this query to update your existing table if you really need to store this data in this specific format.  However, what are you planning to do with the rows that don't appear in the result?  For example, 2,4,5 are you going to delete those rows?   It seems strange that you want to store the data in a denormalized format, when you can use a query to get it in the desired result.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I'd like to avoid the mess asking the same question - just modified. But may be you're right and I should open a new question.

Comment: @Zane - everybody is learning here thanking to the advises from the professionals like BLUEFEET. 
But even based on that - could you give an idea how to leave INTACT at least one additional field between **id** and **group_id** ? Basing on your idea I can learn how to manage with all other fields.

Comment: @bluefeet - I'd like to leave intact the fields 'number" and 'name" what are between **id** and **group_id**. If you could give me an idea how to manage that - I'll manage with other fields based on that.
I don't want to delete any fields in the table.

Comment: @Serge: But this is not learning if you keep asking, "How would I solve this?", "How would I solve that?". You've been given a *working solution*, so please take your time to figure out how it works, specifically what every bit of it does to ultimately return the result you wanted, to the point when you are totally in control of what is going on at every stage of the query. *That* would be learning, and *that* would actually help you to come up with ideas of *your own*.

Comment: @AndriyM - it seems instead of a MySQL solution you offer to discuss philosophical problems relating to self-teaching.
I don't hide the fact I don't know how to solve this and looking for a hint in addition to the perfect code above.
If you're a professional on StackOverflow  - please, offer a solution.

Comment: @Serge Part of the problem at this point is your question is not at all clear. Comments to expand on your OP, but your issue and how you need it resolved is not clear enough to answer.  It seems that you originally provided partial details and as a result you have a partial answer.

Comment: @bluefeet - I simplified my basic table to make my first question simpler to explain the basic problem I have met. 
Now I'm looking for a hint how to leave intact any other fields in table using the code above. 
Yes, that's true, it's expanded question to the same code above.

Comment: @Serge I am not at all clear on what you are asking but if you want to include additional columns, you just need to add them in the final select list.

Comment: @Serge: You *really* need to ask a new question, so that you can illustrate the problem properly (show data samples and the expected result). That will be beneficial for all the parties involved (you, answerers, those searching for answers).

Comment: @bluefeet Thank you for the hint to right direction ! For all non-experienced (like me) - if you need to include more columns - you must correct the code like 
`select d.id, 
t.intact,
d.group_id,` 
where 'intact' means a column what you want to add to a final result from source table.
**BUT THE FINAL QUESTION NOW IS - WHY IT DOES NOT SAVE THE TABLE AFTER PROCESSING ?**
Even using default code above (without any changes) - after refresh it returns table to the initial state.

Comment: @AndriyM - thank you but I solved the problem how to include additional columns - see my comment. So we do not need a new question. But to finalize the matter here - now I'm looking for an answer - why the default code does not save the table after processing ?

Comment: @Serge: A `SELECT` statement alone doesn't save anything, it just returns a result set as requested. There are various methods of saving the results. That is an entirely different problem, though, and you should definitely ask that as a new question, but please try searching first and exploring the given options yourself before asking.

Comment: @AndriyM - I'll follow your advise, will try to learn and manage myself.

Comment: @Serge The version that I provided you will get the result in the format that you want, if you want to store it then you will need to look at using an UPDATE statement.  However, why do you want to store the data in a _denormalized_ format, when you have a way to convert it in the format you want?